# Dar mesmo valor independente da ordem

Tags: php, hash

Eu precisava de alguma forma gerar um "hash" a partir de uma string mas que o mesmo hash seja obtido independente da ordem das duas strings

```
1234+4321  = asdfghjkl
4321+1234  = asdfghjkl
```

isso é possível com PHP?

Comment: A entrada seria duas strings e a saída um hash? Você poderia sempre usar a menor depois a maior (comparando-as lexicograficamente) ou alternativamente fazer o hash de cada uma delas e depois combiná-los com um xor ou `+`.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Sim.. duas strings que na teoria seriam apenas números mas poderiam ser simplesmente palavras também.. poderia explanar sua idéia numa resposta?

Comment: O hash não é para esse propósito e sim devolver o mesmo valor para uma entrada conhecida, por isso é utilizado para verificação de integridade de arquivos e etc...

Comment: Posso sim. Só me esclarece uma coisa: você está pensando num hash tipo tabela hash ou num hash criptográfico?

Comment: @WellingtonSilvaRibeiro entendo, me referi ao hash por que ele mistura as predefinições iniciais..

Comment: @mgibsonbr to pensando num hash normal mesmo, nao focado no uso criptografico mas apenas para embaralhar os dados iniciais.. tipo md5 ou sha1, pra mim tanto faz..

Comment: @user3163662 Acho que você não entendeu: o hash é usado na tabela hash pra indexar um dado (i.e. se você quer colocar as strings numa coleção e quer verificar rapidamente se essas strings estão ou não nessa coleção e/ou mapeá-las para algum outro dado, você usa um tipo de hash). Ou o hash pode ser usado, como apontado pelo Wellington, para mapear sua entrada para uma string única, com o propósito de assegurar a integridade ou talvez a unicidade. E isso normalmente é feito usando outro tipo de hash, tipo MD5, SHA, etc.

Comment: @mgibsonbr fiquei um cado confuso, mas o que eu quero é juntar a string `A` + `B` e independente da ordem em que eu apresente seja A + B ou B + A o código embaralhado com sha1/md5.. seja o mesmo

Comment: @user3163662 Ok, vou escrever uma resposta então. É que a princípio pensei que você queria algo como [isto](https://gist.github.com/netojoaobatista/5065007) ou [isto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804875/php-internal-hashcode-function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vejo duas opções: 1) você compara ambas as strings, e concatena-as de modo que a "menor" (em ordem lexicográfica) esteja sempre primeiro, e então faz o hash das strings concatenadas; 2) você faz o hash de cada string independentemente, e depois combina os resultados usando alguma operação comutativa (como um xor). Exemplos:

```
function hashPar1($a, $b) {
    if ( strcmp($a, $b) > 0 ) {
        $temp = $a;
        $a = $b;
        $b = $temp;
    }
    return hash("sha256", $a . $b);
}

function hashPar2($a, $b) {
    $ha = hash("sha256", $a);
    $hb = hash("sha256", $b);
    $ret = "";
    for( $i=0; $i<strlen($ha); $i++) {
        ret .= chr(ord($ha{$i}) ^ ord($hb{$i}))
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Nota: eu sugiro a segunda opção, pois o primeiro método tem a desvantagem de um número maior de colisões. Por exemplo, o par `foo+bar` produziria o mesmo hash do par `fo+obar` ou `f+oobar` ou `fooba+r` (mas não `foob+ar`). Esse problema não ocorre no segundo método, já que strings distintas teriam hashes totalmente distintos [com alta probabilidade].

**Atualização:** li há pouco [um comentário](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548667/xor-encryption-in-php#comment15045973_7548667) dizendo que no PHP você pode fazer o xor de duas strings diretamente, não precisa quebrá-la em caracteres e converter para e de números. Se isso estiver correto (não testei) então o código da opção 2 pode ser simplificado para:

```
$resultado = hash("sha256", $string1) ^ hash("sha256", $string2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ordene a String e utilize a função de hash. Veja o código abaixo

```
>>> a = '1234+4321'
>>> b = '4321+1234'
>>> a
'1234+4321'
>>> b
'4321+1234'
>>> sorted_a = ''.join(sorted(a))
>>> sorted_a
'+11223344'
>>> sorted_b = ''.join(sorted(b))
>>> sorted_b
'+11223344'
>>> hash(sorted_a)
6594644838925616234
>>> hash(sorted_b)
6594644838925616234
```

Note que o código acima funciona para letras e números. O procedimento utuilizado foi o seguinte:

1. Criou-se variáveis 'a' e 'b'.
2. Variáveis 'a' e 'b' foram ordenada, para que as mesmas fiquem iguais, caso possuam as mesmas letras.
3. Calculou-se o hash da mesmas. Caso possuam as mesmas letras, terão valored de hash iguais.

**Nota:** a pergunta original não especifica a lingaugem, então fiz em python.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi o que o AP quer é que duas strings específicas mapeiem pro mesmo valor, independentemente da ordem, e não que quaisquer strings com os mesmos caracteres o façam. Seu código produziria o mesmo hash para as strings `1234`, `1243`, `1324`, `1342`, `1423`, `1432`, `2134`, ...

Comment: Eu entendi o contrário. Para quaisquer Strings com as mesmas letras, elas devem produzir um mesmo valor de hash.